# How we can send latitude and longitude to MySQL using Android?

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps

Currently I am working with a project to get current latitude and longitude, I got that. Now I want the latitude and longitude send to MySQL database using Android. HTTP part of this program is not working.

```
LocationManager locationManager;
String mprovider;
String lat="", lon="";
private String Tag="MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            postData(lat, lon);

        }
    });


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    mprovider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    if (mprovider != null && !mprovider.equals("")) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(mprovider);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mprovider, 0, 0, this);

        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location Provider Found Check Your Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

private void postData(String la, String lo) {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost htget = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.2/yy.php/"+la+"/"+lo);



    try {
        // Execute HTTP Post Request

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(htget);


        String resp = response.getStatusLine().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, resp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());

    lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    tv.setText("Your Location is:" + lat + "--" + lon);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? These are just normal float values.

Comment: show your web service calling code

Comment: how can i send latitude and longitude to mysql database?

Comment: send it using http request Volley example http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/.

Comment: @Jincy Are you finished building the `web service(Database, Webserver)`?

Answer (score 0):

you can send data form android to server over http. here is more [details](http://guides.codepath.com/android/sending-and-managing-network-requests)

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysql's spatial extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/).

For making tables and using it with Google Maps api refer this:

[Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps)

Before you start, I have few questions:

1. Which version of gmaps API are you working with?
2. How are you parsing the map marker (lat. long.) data?
3. How are you triggering the save (lat long/ map marker data event).

Workable method:  create a JSON parser for parsing the Marker data (which is the JSON Object here).

```
  public class MarkerJSONParser {

/** gets a JSONObject and returns a list */
public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    JSONArray jMarkers = null;
   try {
        /** gets all the elements in the 'markers' array */
        jMarkers = jObject.getJSONArray("markers");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /** enjoining getMarkers with the array of json object
    * here each JSON object is a marker
    */
    return getMarkers(jMarkers);
}

private List<HashMap<String, String>> getMarkers(JSONArray jMarkers){
    int markersCount = jMarkers.length();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> markersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> marker = null;

    /** Parsing and adding each marker to the list object */
    for(int i=0; i<markersCount;i++){
        try {
            /** Call getMarker with marker JSON object to parse the marker */
            marker = getMarker((JSONObject)jMarkers.get(i));
            markersList.add(marker);
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return markersList;
}

/** Parsing the Marker JSON object */
private HashMap<String, String> getMarker(JSONObject jMarker){

    HashMap<String, String> marker = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String lat = "-NA-";
    String lng ="-NA-";

    try {
        // Latitude extraction
        if(!jMarker.isNull("lat")){
            lat = jMarker.getString("lat");
        }

        // Longitude extraction
        if(!jMarker.isNull("lng")){
            lng = jMarker.getString("lng");
        }

        marker.put("lat", lat);
        marker.put("lng", lng);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return marker;
}
}
```

Paste this in your MySQL's MainActivity.java:

```
 // enjoining OnClick Event listener for the GoogleMap
        mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latlng) {
                addMarker(latlng);
                sendToServer(latlng);
            }
        });

        // enjoining location retrieval 
        new RetrieveTask().execute();
    }

    // Marking lat. long. on the GoogleMaps
    private void addMarker(LatLng latlng) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latlng);
        markerOptions.title(latlng.latitude + "," + latlng.longitude);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    // Enjoining bg thread to save marker inMySQL server
    private void sendToServer(LatLng latlng) {
        new SaveTask().execute(latlng);
    }
    // bg thread to save the marker in MySQL server
    private class SaveTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
            String lat = Double.toString(params[0].latitude);
            String lng = Double.toString(params[0].longitude);
            String strUrl = "http://www.yourserverurllocation.com";
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                connection.getOutputStream());

                outputStreamWriter.write("lat=" + lat + "&lng="+lng);
                outputStreamWriter.flush();
                outputStreamWriter.close();

                InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";

                while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
                iStream.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```